# Ayuda con consultas de access

Tags: ms-access, sql

Estoy haciendo una base de datos del stock del departamento de informática de mi empresa. Soy prácticamente bastante nueva en Access, me he visto algunos tutoriales sobre hacer esto con las macros, pero no me salía después de muchos intentos de "Prueba y error" y acabé buscando otras maneras.

Vi que con consultas se podría obtener un resultado parecido, así que intenté eso, después de ver unos cuantos vídeos y leer sobre como realizarlas, logré sacar una estructura, pero aún haciendo lo mismo de los vídeos, no salía el mismo resultado.

> **Tengo estas tablas:**
>
> Articulos: Id, Articulo, Descripción, Stock, Ubicación
>
> Pedidos: Id, Producto, Asignado a, Cantidad, Fecha
>
> Personal: Código, Nombre, Apellido 1, Apellido 2.
>
> **Tengo estas consultas:**
>
> Stock_Prestado: Asignado a, Producto, Cantidad, Fecha.
>
> Stock_Restante: Artículo, descripción, Ubicación, Stock_Restante

El campo "Stock_Restante" de la consulta Stock_Restante tiene esta forma a la hora de hacer la consulta: `Stock_Restante: [Articulos]![Stock]-[Pedidos]![Cantidad]`

Ahora venían unos cuantos problemas.

- En la consulta Stock_Restante el campo calculado no muestra nada.
  [image: Stock_Restante]
- Cuando entro en la consulta Stock_Restante, sale una ventana emergente.
  [image: Stock_Restante]
- ¿Hay alguna forma (sin macros) de actualizar el campo Stock de la tabla Artículos para que se reste a la cantidad cuando se registre un pedido?

En su defecto estoy usando una consulta que me muestre esto, pero quería ver si es posible calcular algo ahí. Intenté con un campo calculado, pero no se podían seleccionar campos de otras tablas.

Adjunto captura de pantalla del diseño de la consulta en Access:
[image: Diseño de la Consulta]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ese parámetro te pide introducirlo porque escribes el nombre de un campo que Access desconoce porque no le has indicado de dónde obtenerlo. Debes añadir, al diseño de la consulta, la tabla a la que estás haciendo referencia y prescindir de los agrupamientos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De esa forma obtendrás este resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En respuesta a tu comentario, tendrías que usar un `LEFT JOIN`, aunque también deberías diseñar una consulta intermedia llamada `Total_Pedidos` que calcule los totales pedidos de cada artículo y utilizar ese dato, en vez del de la tabla `Pedidos`, para calcular tu stock actualizado (te envío las consultas en SQL para evitar las capturas de pantalla):

```
SELECT Pedidos.Producto, Sum(Pedidos.Cantidad) AS SumaDeCantidad
FROM Pedidos
GROUP BY Pedidos.Producto;
```

Con esta subconsulta definida, ya puedes modificar `Stock_Restante` de forma que responda a este SQL:

```
SELECT Articulos.Articulo, 
Articulos.Descripción, Articulos.Ubicación, IIf(IsNull(
[Articulos]![Stock]-[Total_Pedidos]![SumaDeCantidad]),
[Articulos]![Stock],
[Articulos]![Stock]-[Total_Pedidos]![SumaDeCantidad]
) AS Stock_Restante
FROM Total_Pedidos 
RIGHT JOIN Articulos 
ON Total_Pedidos.Producto = Articulos.Id;
```

Comment: ¡Genial! ¿Y cómo puedo hacer para que se muestre el resultado de cada artículo, aún si nadie lo ha pedido todavía?